# Initializing IBOutletCollection Issue in ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an `IBOutletCollection` of `UILabel` and I store this property like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection (UILabel) NSMutableArray *labelCollection.
```

This isn't my root view controller and I'm bouncing between this controller and the main controller when an event occurs.
When said event occurs, I `segue` from the main controller to this view controller. Whenever this happens, my collection becomes a new collection and all the data from before is erased. However when the initialization occurs in the `init` or `initWithNibName` method, I end up accessing and working with a null `IBOutletCollection`. How would I go about creating this collection and storing and accessing the data optimally without declaring it in the main view controller? Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that the controller itself (and all its properties, including your collection) is being deallocated when you leave it. You need to keep a reference to that controller and push or present the same one every time you go to it.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work out. My UILabels are actually updating now with desired output.